# Google Play 30% transaction fee

Tags: android, google-play

Google support states that:
"*For applications and in-app products that you sell on Google Play, the transaction fee is equivalent to 30% of the price.
You receive 70% of the payment. The remaining 30% goes to the distribution partner and operating fees.*"

I'd like to clarify the following:

1. If I'd like to upload an application to Google Play Store that's just an apk webview wrapper (so it's basically web-based app). If I set a download price, does the transaction fee of 30% still apply?
2. If I incorporate a Visa or PayPal transaction inside the app (not for buying in-app products but mostly for depositing and withdrawing money regarding sports betting and slots gambling), does the transaction fee of 30% still apply for this "money" movements?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google Play's pricing policies and doesn't involve programming.

Comment: Why exactly do you vote to close the issue, since google play advises Stack Overflow for this kind of Android questions?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, what you're asking is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google Play's pricing policies and doesn't involve programming

Answer (score 4):

Transaction fee which is equivalent to 30% of the price applies to absolutely all applications (regardless their content) and in-app products that you sell on Google Play. You receive 70% of the payment. The remaining 30% goes to the distribution partner and operating fees.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622

According to the [Google Play Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> **In-app purchases:**
>
> - Developers offering virtual goods or currencies
>     within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's
>     in-app billing service as the method of payment.
> - Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except: >
>
>   - where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription); or
>   - where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can be played on other music players).

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622

Comment: in my app consultants answer users's questions and users have to pay for this. Do i have to use only Google Play's in-app billing service? Can i use another payment API?